# How can I revert/roll back to an earlier version of a file from Subversive?

Tags: rollback, subversive

I'm completely new to source control and Subversive, and I've committed changes to a file that shouldn't have been modified.  I've done over an hour of searching documentation and the Internet about this, but I guess I'm not familiar enough with the terminology.  Also, a lot of source control resources seem to be for command line users.

Here's what I've tried so far: first, I used the Team > Revert option, but I've since found that that only affect the local copy.  I looked at the repository's web interface, but it only provided a diff tool, not a rollback tool.  I've also opened the History tab and found "Revert Changes from Revision X" and "Switch to Revision X" in context menus.

Based on the docs I've found, I think one of those is what I need, but I'm not sure which.  Also, I don't know whether to select the current revision, because that's the one I want to undo, or the one before it, because that's the one I want to get to.  If this were a code problem, I'd just run a little test, but in this case I'm afraid I'll make things worse by selecting the wrong option and I don't want to clutter the repository with a useless test file.

So, in summary: **How can I use Subversive to roll back a single file to its immediately previous version?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert is the right command. You can not "undo" a commit on the server so that it is not visible. What you need to do is revert the changes from that revision (or revert *to* the revision before the revision with your changes, I think both options are presented in subclipse's log), which rolls back your working copy to the state it was before, and then commit.

Also: Which is it? Subversive or subclipse?

Comment: Is there any difference between this and copying the contents of the old version into the file and re-committing?

Comment: Sorry, I retagged, it's Subversive.  When I started writing the post, I didn't realize they were different, which shows you how much I know about source control.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus
Yes, there is a difference, but probably not in your case. The difference is that you can also revert changes from a revision later on, even after the file has been changed by others, because it is handled by the merge-logic in SVN, which uses diffs generated for the revisions. If it was the last version, then no, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the version you want using:

```
svn co http://example.com/svn/reponame/dir/file.ext -R 123
```

Or if it wasn't committed, you can use

```
svn revert file.ext
```